# Why does indolizine undergo EAS on C3 and not C5 of the pyrrole ring?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, resonance

In Clayden, Greeves, & Warren: Organic Chemistry Second Edition, it is said that indolizine (pyrrocoline) reacts in electrophilic aromatic substitution at the C3 of the pyrrole ring, as shown. [image]

I understand that it reacts at the pyrrole ring because the pyrrole ring is more nucleophilic than the pyridine-like ring, but I don't understand why it doesn't react at the C5 position of the pyrrole ring (like pyrrole does); the sigma complex at the C5 position has more extensive delocalization, whereas the sigma complex at C3 is less stable cross-conjugation.

Comment: Meh, it's not like things like that can be reliably explained like this, in general.

Comment: @Mithoron Then what would you say are the concepts which explain this?